# How to define associations in hibernate file

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a query which when i run in sqlDeveloper i get the result. Here is the query

```
select * from Losa_Cust_Reject_App rejectApp 
inner join 
    Losa_Cust losaCust 
on 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No = losaCust.app_Ref_No 
where 
    rejectApp.app_Ref_No != '0000001912' and  rejectApp.app_Dt >= '23-SEP-2012' 
and
    rejectApp.cust_Id1 = 'A111111111' and rejectApp.cust_Id1_Type = '01';
```

i translated this query to hibernate as following

```
public List findAppByDate(String appRefNo, Date previousAppDate, String currentId1,
    String currentIdType1) {

    StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("from ");
    query.append(LosaCustRejectApp.class.getName());
    query.append(" rejectApp inner join ");
    query.append(LosaCust.class.getName());
    query.append(" losaCust with rejectApp.appRefNo = losaCust.comp_id.appRefNo");
    query.append(" where rejectApp.appRefNo != ? and  rejectApp.appDt >= ?");
    query.append(" and rejectApp.custId1 = ? and rejectApp.custId1Type = ? ");

    List result = null;

    try {
        result = getHibernateTemplate().find(query.toString(),
            new Object[] { appRefNo, previousAppDate, currentId1, currentIdType1 });

        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(result)) {
            return result;
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        String message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println();
    }
    return result;
}
```

But i want to define mapping in hibernate so hibernate make the join automatically. How can i define association in hibernate file for the above query so hibernate make the join automatically.

here is my LosaCustReject.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaCustRejectApp" table="LOSA_CUST_REJECT_APP" optimistic-lock="version">

    <id name="rejectAppId" type="java.lang.Long" column="REJECT_APP_ID">
        <generator class="com.thetasp.code.runningno.HibernateId">
            <param name="fieldCode">REJECT_APP_ID</param>
            <param name="returnType">java.lang.Long</param>
        </generator>
    </id>
    <version name="rowVersion" type="int" column="ROW_VERSION" access="property" unsaved-value="undefined" />
    <property name="appRefNo" type="java.lang.String" column="APP_REF_NO" not-null="true" length="20" />
    <property name="appDt" type="java.sql.Timestamp" column="APP_DT" not-null="true" length="23" />
    <property name="custId1Type" type="java.lang.String" column="CUST_ID1_TYPE" not-null="true" length="1" />
    <property name="custId1" type="java.lang.String" column="CUST_ID1" not-null="true" length="20" />
    .......
    <property name="updateDt" type="java.sql.Timestamp" column="UPDATE_DT" length="23" />

    <!-- associations -->
</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

LosaCust.hbm.xml

```
<hibernate-mapping default-lazy="false">
<class name="com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaCust" table="LOSA_CUST" discriminator-value="I" optimistic-lock="version">

    <composite-id name="comp_id" class="com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaCustPK">
        <key-property name="custId" column="CUST_ID" type="java.lang.String" length="20" />
        <key-property name="appRefNo" column="APP_REF_NO" type="java.lang.String" length="20" />
    </composite-id>

    <discriminator column="CUST_T" type="string" length="1" >
    </discriminator>

    <version name="rowVersion" type="int" column="ROW_VERSION" access="property" unsaved-value="undefined" />
    <property name="custLevel" type="java.lang.String" column="CUST_LEVEL" not-null="false" length="10" />
              .....
    <property name="staySinceMth" type="java.lang.String" column="STAYED_SINCE_MTH" length="10" />
            ....
    <subclass name="com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaIndvCust" discriminator-value="I" lazy="false" >
        <property name="id1Type" type="java.lang.String" column="ID1_TYPE" length="1" />
        <property name="id1" type="java.lang.String" column="ID1" length="20" />
         ....

 </subclass>

</class>
```

Thanks

Comment: Depending on the relationship you wanna set between the tables you will have to use  <many-to-one>, <one-to-many> or <one-to-one> elements in your xml mapping

Comment: for each Losa Cust i have many records in LosaCustRejectApp. Like based on the query that i made i get 12 records when i run in sql developer

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do something like this

In LosaCust.java define a field representing the one-to-many association to LosaCustRejectApp entities:

```
List<LosaCustRejectApp> associatedLosaCustRejectApps;
```

In LosaCust.hbm.xml you map this new field using something like this:

```
<list name="associatedLosaCustRejectApps" table="LOSA_CUST_REJECT_APP" >
    <key>
        <column name="app_Ref_No" not-null="true" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaCustRejectApp" />
</set>
```

For more details and even a complete tutorial on how to do this type of mapping you can go here:

[Hibernate – One-to-Many example (XML Mapping)](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-one-to-many-relationship-example/)

Best regards